# Проблема с установкой Ubuntu рядом с Windows: ACPI Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, uefi

После монитрования Ubuntu на флешку, при попытке установить её рядом с Windows, сразу же после старта компьютера и "запуска флешки" (комп включается, выбираю загрузку с флешки, начинает загружаться, но вскоре появляется то, что на фото) выдаёт ошибку с фото и больше ничего не делает.

Подскажите как решить проблему. Пробовал уже разные конфигурации в Rufus и разные флешки - ничего не помогло. Раньше не мог установить и Windows сюда, была такая же ошибка, исправил её покупкой новой флешки, но щас через ту же флешку не выходит для Ubuntu.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Безошибочная установка линукс на ноутбук, это большая удача, а проблемы это норма

Comment: `noacpi` в параметры ядра добавлял?

Comment: Не знал что законно что-то добавлять)
Погуглю про это и попробую, спасибо!

Comment: То, что на фото, следствие, а не причина. Ошибка где-то раньше. По выпадающему в осадок циклу скорее всего ждёт-не-дождётся события от embedded controller.

Comment: noacpi так понял можно добавить если стоит Linux, а у меня Windows.
Производитель ноутбука сказал, что Ubuntu не поддерживается, так что оставлю попытки установить его.
(Debian кстати ставится без проблем)